# How does Django Rest Framework deserialize foreign key relationships?

Tags: python, django, api, serialization, django-rest-framework

In the tutorial, there's this loose one-to-one mapping between serializer fields and model fields. I can expect that if a serializer field and a model field are both CharFields it will save a string of characters when deserializing into a model instance:

models.py:

```
    class Deck(models.Model):
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
```

serializers.py:

```
class DeckSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Deck
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'created', 'name')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {
                'view_name': 'goals:deck-detail',
            }
        }
```

But when I try a relationship, the serializer field is a ReadOnlyField, which from what I understand is essentially a Charfield, but the model field is a ForeignKeyField, and to add to the confusion, it seems like I'm saving an object in the views when I override perform_create:

models.py:

```
class Deck(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', related_name='decks', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
```

serializers.py:

```
class DeckSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Deck
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'created', 'name', 'user')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {
                'view_name': 'goals:deck-detail',
            }
        }
```

views.py:

```
class DeckList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = DeckSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Deck.objects.all().filter(user__username=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

What's going on here? When dealing with relationships, why is it that I am saving an object by overriding perform_create in the views, declaring in the serializers a CharField, and in the models declaring a relationship field?

What's missing in my understanding, or what's really happening under the hood such that the user field (ForeignKey) can be represented as a string but saved as an object?

**Edit:**

If I'm overriding serializer.save(user=user) in the views and the serializers.py has the user field as

```
user = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
```

And I want to override the save method in serializers.py, how do I pass the proper data so that it will know how to serialize? Do I just grab the whole User object, save it, and it'll do the rest? Is the serializers.save() override in the views the same as serializers.save() in serializers.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure that I've understood what you're asking, but if the question is:

> What's happening under the hood when a ForeignKey field is saved in the Django ORM?

Then the answer is that:

> The relation is saved in the DB as an (e.g.) int field which stores the primary key of the related object.

The [ForeignKey field reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) section in the Django docs explains how this part of the ORM works, and the ["Database Representation"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#database-representation) subsection likely touches on the specific bit you're interested in.

For example, for your case of `User` being a related field in the `Deck` model the underlying table would likely look like this (assuming postgresql):

```
myapp_deck
    id         int
    created    timestamp
    name       varChar
    user_id    int
```

The `Deck -> User` relation is mapped by the DB storing the pk for the related User object in the `user_id` field in the `myapp_deck` table.

So, all Django (and, consequently, DRF) needs to do to change the `User` in the `Deck` model is change the `user_id` in the `myapp_deck` table  to the PK of a different `User` object.

Hope this helps, and please let me know if I've missed the point of your question.

---

**Edited to Add Example of Custom .create() method**

If you want to override the custom "save" method in a serializer then the methods to override are `create()` and `update()` accordingly (see [Serializer "Saving instances"](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) section in the DRF docs).

An example of this might be:

```
class DeckSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')

    ... Rest of your serializer code ...

    def create(self, validated_data, **kwargs):
        user_obj = User.objects.get(pk=validated_data["user"])
        deck = Deck.objects.create(
            name=validated_data["name"],
            user=user_obj,
        )
        return deck
```

**Note:** This assumes that the `pk` of the related `User` object is passed throught the serializer, validates OK, and is available in the `validated_data` dict.

Comment: This helps me a bit more, I didn't know it was stored as an int field in Django. What I don't get is a high level overview of how the serializer in DRF is doing what it is for foreign keys. 

With a normal incoming field like 'name': 'bob' coming in form json, I can understand that the view passes to the serializer that field and that field would have something like name: serializers.CharField(), which expects a string and deserializes into a model instance as a string because the model field will also have name = models.CharField().

Comment: But with a foreign key, the view passes an object in perform_create, the serializer takes a CharField, and the model stores a ForeignKey Field, which is supposed to be an int field? I guess what I'm trying to ask is how do serializers do this magic conversion/mapping from object to string to int and back? Or is it just accepted magic that happens under the hood?

What if I wanted to overwrite the save method in the serializers? How would it know to pick the correct user object if I just save a string property off the user object? I don't think I can serialize a whole object in serializers

Comment: I've edited my answer to show an example of a custom ``create()`` method. Hopefully that let's you see what's going on "under the hood". Is your code doing what you want it to?

Comment: The code does what I want it to and your explanation makes sense, but the one thing I don't understand now is the serializer field validation for 'user'. If Django saves the foreign key relationship as an int_field, shouldn't the field validation fail because it's using a CharField (ReadOnlyField)? Or maybe what it's doing is saving an int field in 'user_id', but keeping 'user' as a CharField?

Comment: Nevermind, I think it's all starting to click now. The ReadOnlyField is validated and used only for serialization and not deserialization and if I wanted to make it writable I'd write a custom create() like you said.